# How do I get user input from EditTextPreference (and do something with it)?

Tags: android, input, dialog, edittextpreference

I have defined a PreferenceScreen in XML, containing several EditTextPreference "objects". I want to catch user input from these fields, but I can't see to figure out how. The answer would seem to lie here, but I'm not gettng it: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/EditTextPreference.html

I'm guessing it's similar to this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder ( this );
final EditText input = new EditText ( this );
    alert.setView ( input );

    alert.setPositiveButton ( "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener () {
        public void onClick ( DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton ) {
            c.setName ( input.getText ().toString () );
        }
    } );
```

Comment: Have a look at http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html#tutorial_preferenceactivity

Comment: Please show your xml too

Comment: the above code will crash, if the user clicks `OK` with entering any data. add `if(input.getText ().length()>0)`{c.setName....}, but this is not the answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other Activity, you can use PreferenceScreen as a PreferenceActivity. And its corresponding class looks like below:

```
public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);// point your xml file
  }
}
```

Don't forget to register this class as an activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

To show the Preference screen, just call it as a usual Activity as:

```
Intent i = new Intent(OverviewActivity.this, MyPreferencesActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

And you can access its values as

```
SharedPreferences  preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String username = preferences.getString("your_key", "default_value");
```

For more reference, Hava a look at http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html#tutorial_preferenceactivity

Comment: @CaptainHindsight: If problem is solved, then you can mark this answer as useful(Tick mark above) and so the question will not remain as unanswered.

Comment: Ah, there you go. Done.